# sorting an array based on the value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array based on a value. I have an array for example

```
arr = [{t1: 'test1', t2: 'bca' },
       {t1: 'test2', t2: 'cab'},
       {t1: 'test', t2: 'abc'}]
```

I want to sort above array based on the value t2 in alphabetical order.
the array after sorting should look like below.

```
arr = [{t1: 'test', t2: 'abc' },
       {t1: 'test1', t2: 'bca'},
       {t1: 'test2', t2: 'cab'}]
```

Please guide me how can i achieve this. THanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the `sort` function of an array

```js
arr = [{
    t1: "test1",
    t2: "bca"
  },
  {
    t1: "test2",
    t2: "cab"
  },
  {
    t1: "test",
    t2: "abc"
  },
];

arr.sort(function(x, y) {
  if (x.t2 < y.t2) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (x.t2 > y.t2) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
});

console.log(arr);
```